# Running 32bit linux (ubuntu) application on 64bit

Tags: x86, 32bit-64bit, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to run a 32bit executable developed on ubuntu 18.04 32bit on ubuntu 22.04 64bit.
The applciation is compiled with GNU GCC Compiler with CodeBlocks (with -m32 flags)
On Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit works fine.
I've added the architecture on ubuntu 22.04 and also needed libraries

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386

The application depends on libgtksourceview2.0.
I've installed it and it's present in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
the path is also added on /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

When I try to run the applicatin I get the following error:

**error while loading shared libraries: libgtksourceview-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
**

I've also tryed to compile the application on ubuntu 22.04 but all libraries which are installed under x86_64-linux-gnu seem to not be on search path.

Also other application which depends on libraries under that folder do not start.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

I've tried to add the path on ld.so.conf.d.
I've installed the library libgtksourceview several times

this is a part of *ldd application*

```
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0xf7328000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7223000)
libgtksourceview-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf715c000)
libX11.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf700d000)
```

I expect the application will run even on 64 bit environment

Comment: Ubuntu dropped support for 32bit applications a few years ago. I take it you don't have the source code? You could maybe try using a decompiler like Snowman and then re-compile it for 64 bit. I've never used it though so can't help with details.

Comment: Hi Simon. Thank you for your reply.
As I read it's possibile to run 32 bit application on Ubuntu adding the platform architecture. 
I try to rebuild but also the compilere do not find libraries under that folder.

Comment: @SimonGoater It's true that Ubuntu has dropped the 32-bit architecture, but x86-64 has compatibility mode, which can run 32-bit code. Therefore, x86-64 can run 32-bit (like i386) applications.

Comment: @couyoh I'm aware of the backward compatibility of x86_64. If it were a static binary, maybe it would work. I guess it's the syscalls and dynamic linking functions that are the issue. If the packages for 32 bit support are developed and available, why did Ubuntu decide to stop shipping with them? This is outside of my area of expertise, but I suspect there's no easy way to run 32 bit binaries on 64bit Ubuntu releases. I'm interested to see if the OP can get it working though...

Comment: @SimonGoater I think the kernel supports i386 syscall, but I agree with dependency hell. [Ubuntu provides selected i386 package](https://canonical.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts), but `libgtksourceview2` looks gone even on x86-64. In this case, it's certainly not easy in that manual builds are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit code.

You said you added the `-m32` flag. It means your application is 32-bit.
But you also said that `libgtksourceview2.0` is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. It's considered 64-bit. (You can check by `readelf -h`).

Therefore, you need to build `libgtksourceview2.0` in 32-bit, and then add it to the library path.

To add the library path, I think it's better to specify the built path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Other than that, copy built files to the path that is defined at `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`. In your case, probably `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`.

Comment: Hi Couyoh.
I though that x86_64-linux-gnu contains both 64 and 32 bit compatible libs.
Now, i've manually removed the libgtksourceview2.0 from that folder and copied on usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu a version picked from ubuntu 18.04 32bit.
I've delete the ld cache and recreated and now this application has started.
My question is: there's no way to install 32 bit version of libs on ubuntu 22.04 64bit?
I've an other application to run and it depends on other libs...and do that manually is an hard work

Comment: [Ubuntu provides selected i386 package](https://canonical.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts). But yes, you probably won't be able to _package install_ all the necessary libraries in your case. The best way is to get the latest 64-bit version of that program (if available). Anyway, you can _install_ by the library code build manually (If the library source code is available).